# Bad graphics performance using Cinnamon instead of Unity

Tags: unity, nvidia, performance, desktop-environments, cinnamon

I installed cinnamon 3.0 on Ubuntu 16.04, everything's works fine but performance is way worse than on Unity.

I use this ppa :https://launchpad.net/~embrosyn/+archive/ubuntu/cinnamon

Using glxgears, I got around 25000 fps in Unity while I get only ~10000 in Cinnamon. Same with Unigine Valley benchmark, 35 fps in extreme HD preset in Unity, and 24 in Cinnamon.

Is there anything I can do to get the same performance ? I'd like to completely switch to Cinnamon.

My graphic card is a Nvidia card, and I'm using prime to use it permanently.

Comment: There's a disclaimer in the PPA: *"(...) everything available here is provided "as is", without any warranty"* . Cinnamon probably work better in Mint.

Comment: I fresh-installed Linux Mint and Ubuntu-Gnome to test it but the results are the same even with a fresh install of those (nvidia-367 + nvidia-prime). Seems I can't use the nVidia card with proprietary drivers outside Unity.